# Docker host config has wrong IP address

Tags: linux, docker, networking, raspbian

I'm trying to install Docker on Raspbian but it seems to have picked up an old config from somewhere.  No idea where from, as I can't find any references anywhere.

I have installed Docker on Raspbian using `sudo apt-get install docker-ce`.

When I try to connect to Docker, it tries to connect to the wrong IP address (192.168.1.75 when it should be 192.168.1.227).

```
$ docker ps
error during connect: Get http://192.168.1.75:2376/v1.38/containers/json: dial tcp 192.168.1.75:2376: connect: no route to host
```

The server *used* to be on 192.168.1.75 but is now on 192.168.1.227.

```
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:50:b4:16  
          inet addr:192.168.1.227  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:42704 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61093 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6278037 (5.9 MiB)  TX bytes:80578119 (76.8 MiB)
```

I've tried rebooting the server, deleting the contents of the `/var/run/docker` folder, and even reinstalling Docker.  It's still determined that the IP address is 192.168.1.75.

Comment: Thanks. You are completely correct.  As a developer trying to set up Docker at home, I completely forgot to switch over to ServerFault or Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the machine where the docker command tries to connect with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable:

> export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.1.227:2376"

But it's strange that you have to do this on a default installation, perhaps they is a DOCKER_HOST variable in you bash/zsh profile that cause this problem ?

Comment: That's exactly what it was.  I cannot believe I forgot to check the variables.  Thanks!